# Python using while loop with a list name

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am a beginner to python so this might be easy but I am not sure of what the following code means.

```
q=[start]
    while q:
```

Does this mean when there is at least one element in the list q execute it and q becomes false when it is empty?
Edit:I cannot execute it at the moment and I need to find it quickly.

Comment: `q = [start]` means 'make a list called `q`, and put the variable `start` in as the first element'. `while q:` means 'repeat the following indented block until it is empty' (because lists coerce to boolean `True` while non-empty and `False` while empty). Is the indentation as you are showing here though? If so, it won't run correctly.

Comment: This is just a part the code.So my assumption was correct.Thanks for the comment you can write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `q = [start]` means *create a variable called `q`, and assign the value `[start]` to it*. In this case, it will create a list with one element: the value of the variable `start`. It's the exact same syntax as `q = [1, 2]`, but it uses a variable instead of a constant value.

After this, the line `while q:` is a use (or abuse) of Python's type conversion system. While loops require a boolean condition to know whether they should repeat, so your code is equivalent to `while bool(q):`. To understand how this works, let's examine the possible cases:

```
bool([1]) == True # This applies for any non-empty list
bool([]) == False # This applies to any empty list
```

Therefore, the meaning of `while q:` is actually 'while `q` is non-empty'.